# El url solicitado no es valido para este comando ftp

Tags: vb.net

Estoy teniendo problemas al intentar descargar un archivo vía FTP, me sale el error y tampoco se cambia la visibilidad de los botones de instalar e iniciar y la idea es cuando se descarguen los archivos del servidor FTP cambie la opacidad de los dos para que este el botón de iniciar en vez del de instalar

> El URI solicitado no es valido para este comando FTP.

```
    Private Sub Botonweon2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Botonweon2.Click
        If (Not Directory.Exists("C:\Program Files\DEV_RETARDS\APOCALYPSE")) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Program Files\DEV_RETARDS\APOCALYPSE")
        End If ' Crear directorio si no existe '
        Main()
        FTP()
        Botonweon.Visible = True ' Boton de Iniciar '
    End Sub
    Private Sub FTP()
        Dim localFile As String = "C:\Program Files\DEV_RETARDS\APOCALYPSE"
        Dim GAMENAME As String = "htdocs/APOCALYPSE/Descarga esto"
        Dim remoteFile As String = GAMENAME
        Const host As String = "ftp://ftpupload.net/" 'nombre de la carpeta en nuestro server FTP donde estan los archivos que deseamos descargar
        ' colocamos el nombre de usuario y password respectivo para acceder al server, si este no poseyera, dejar solo las comillas, osea ""
        Const username As String = "USER"
        Const password As String = "PASS"
        Dim URI As String = host + remoteFile ' nombre completo de la ruta del archivo
        Dim ftp As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = CType(Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), Net.FtpWebRequest)
        ftp.Credentials = New _
System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)
        ftp.KeepAlive = False
        ftp.UseBinary = True
        ftp.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
        Try
            Using response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse =
CType(ftp.GetResponse, System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
                Using responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
                    Using fs As New IO.FileStream(localFile, IO.FileMode.Create)
                        Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
                        Dim read As Integer = 0
                        Do
                            read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                            fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                        Loop Until read = 0
                        responseStream.Close()
                        fs.Flush()
                        fs.Close()
                    End Using
                    responseStream.Close()
                End Using
                response.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
           Dim strError As String = ex.ToString()
        End Try
        Botonweon2.Visible = False ' Boton de Instalar '
    End Sub
```

Salida: 'Demo.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Demo.exe): 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_es_b77a5c561934e089\System.resources.dll' cargado. El módulo se compiló sin símbolos.
Excepción producida: 'System.Net.WebException' en System.dll

Capturado en variable strError: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87714/discussion-on-question-by-gabri2233-el-url-solicitado-no-es-valido-para-este-com).